# Is it possible to declare one's own [mini] namespace within an NSUUID?

Tags: swift, namespaces, uuid, nsuuid

The Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier states that in version 3 (and therefore presumably 5) of the UUID spec: "**Six bits are replaced by fixed values**"

I am working on an iPhone app that utilises the `NSUUID` class. My client has asked for the ability to declare his own small fixed set of chars within the full UUID string. From what I have read thus far, I don't think this is possible - for *just loads* for understandable reasons - however I am obliged to ask whether there is a way, so that I can answer/deflect his questions with surety.

So is there or not, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no API but there is obviously a way to do it. question is how important uniqueness is, being able to prove that uniqueness and the side effects of failure...

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible?  Of course; but unless your client's iPhone app lives in an alternate universe, perhaps your client's iPhone app would be better served by sticking to the versions described by the RFC 4122 variant.

It might be helpful to sit down with your client and explain the uuid layout.  You might consider using [Mahonri Moriancumer's UUID and GUID Generator and Forensics](http://www.mahonri.info/cgi/uuid.cgi) to demonstrate UUID options.

**Update:**  In thinking this through a bit more, there is a way to add a signature to generated UUIDs...

Consider the version 1 UUID structure (RFC 4122 variant).  For this type of UUID, the last 12 digits represent the MAC address of the computer's ethernet card that generated the UUID.

If you were to get the MAC address from a specific ethernet card (even an old, obsolete one), and then destroy the card, you could be assured that no other computer will ever generate a UUID (v1) using that ethernet card's MAC address ever again.  Then you could use that MAC address as your ***"own small fixed set of chars within the full UUID string"***.

Then, just write your own UUID v1 generator that uses this mac address as the last 12 digits of the UUID.  The rest of the UUID digits could comply with the v1 spec.  The resulting generated UUIDs would be fully complient with the v1 spec, and could be identified (as a set) by the last 12 digits.